R plotting issue
I want a simple line graph showing the total expenses for each department for each fiscal year.
This is the image that I keep getting
This is my code here//
    # Convert negative amounts to absolute values
    Sac$Amount <- ifelse(Sac$Amount < 0, abs(Sac$Amount), Sac$Amount)

    # Get unique departments
    departments <- unique(Sac$Department)

    # Create and save line plots for each department
    for (dept in departments) {
      # Subset data for the current department
      dept_data <- Sac[Sac$Department == dept, ]
  
      # Create line plot
      p <- ggplot(dept_data, aes(x = Fiscal.Year, y = Amount)) +
        geom_line() +
        labs(x = "Fiscal Year", y = "Amount (Absolute)", title = paste("Department:", dept)) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(dept_data$Fiscal.Year), labels =           unique(dept_data$Fiscal.Year)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) +
        theme_minimal()
  
      # Save as PNG file in your RStudio directory
      filename <- paste("department_expenses_", gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", dept), ".png", sep = "")
      ggsave(filename, plot = p, width = 12, height = 8, units = "in", dpi = 300)
    }

This was done in excel, but  want it to look like this format wise
I am a complete newbie to R so I tried using Google and YouTube to help me resolve this issue, but to no avail. I then resorted to ChatGpt which isn't giving me what I need. This is also my first time on Stack OverFlow so I apologize if I am missing some things

This is a not a plotting issue but a data format issue. Without seeing a sample of your data, I can't provide any advice.  Please edit your question and add sample of your data (any dept should work) using the output of the dput(dept_data).

My first guess would be that you have multiple datapoints for department/year combinations.  You probably want to sum them before plotting

^ or map the different combinations to different colors, or at least different groups.

You should specify the variable that distinguishes the categories in aes(). Based on the indicated variables, it should be aes(x = Fiscal.Year, y = Amount, color = variable_name), where variable_name represents the variable that differentiates between revenue and expenses.
